# What is the independent variable where it is not shown

Tags: calculus

I have been asked to state the dependent and independent variable in the equation $x'' + 5x = e^{-x}$.

The dependent variable is $x$ but I don't know what to put as the independent variable. Any idea?

Comment: Think about what $x''$ means.

Comment: That is the second derivative of x in terms of a certain variable

Comment: You can give that variable a name. What does your text use as the default? Time?

Comment: The names of the variables have changed. Time $t$ is now your independent variable. Look at some other examples.

Comment: The first two questions had y as the dependent variable and x as the independent. But they were other equations sharing the same question of "What the dependent and the independent variable"
y′=y−x^2
xy′=2y
For these the answers are abvious

Comment: Your question has been answered.